# Can I use one lando file to for multiple projects?

Tags: docker, lando

I have a couple of github repos that I want to configure and start using one lando file ? Do I have to use multiple lando files or can it be just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lando](https://github.com/lando/lando) is for defining a development environment.

considering that [`lando init`](https://docs.lando.dev/basics/init.html) is for creating a `.lando.yml` for a given recipe and with code from a given source.
It initializes a codebase for usage with Lando.

So this seems specific for a given code-base, and should be created in each of your GitHub repositories.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to have to have like a main recipe that calls the recipes from the other repos

Comment: @mosaad If all your projects follow the same environment/toolset, you might consider having one GitHub repo dedicated to a (one) lando environment, and your other repos would use it (through for instance a git submodule declaration)